# Android pick activity text color

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, shortcut

I have a problem with pick activity, i have this popup :

[image]

Text color is white and background too.
This is code i use :

```
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    ArrayList<String> shortcutNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    shortcutNames.add(getString(R.string.group_applications));
    bundle.putStringArrayList(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, shortcutNames);

    ArrayList<ShortcutIconResource> shortcutIcons = new ArrayList<ShortcutIconResource>();
    shortcutIcons.add(ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, shortcutIcons);

    Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK_ACTIVITY);
    pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT));
    pickIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, getText(R.string.app_name));
    pickIntent.putExtras(bundle);

    startActivityForResult(pickIntent, 1);
```

Comment: I have same issue with Android 4.2 I think I will implement list by myself. You can get items from PackageManager.queryIntentActivities()
For Android implementation look here: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/ActivityPicker.java

Comment: Yes, and it's still broken in 4.2.1.

Comment: Thanks !!! I will implement my dialog

Comment: I'm having the same issue in my application Car Dashboard. Works fine in Android 4.1, but Android 4.2 shows the same white text on white background.

Comment: Still broken in 4.2.2 :(

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution:

You need to use

```
Intent pickIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
```

The rest is still the same.
This code will give you the Holo dialog.

Comment: That doesn't help very much if you need to do something with the chosen activity before it is actually started, such as granting permissions for a resource to the activity's package that will persist (as using an intent with `Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` can cause issues when the activity holds on to the URI beyond its life cycle, such as with attachments for an e-mail or the like, and prior to Jelly Bean it doesn't work for URIs stored in Extras anyway).